# Number of subgroups isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{2}\times \mathbb{Z}_{2}$ in $D_8$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-presentation, dihedral-groups

Let
$$D_8=\langle \sigma,\rho \; | \; \rho^8=\sigma^2=e \text{ and } \sigma\rho\sigma=\rho^{-1} \rangle $$
be the dihedral group of 16 elements. First of all I found the number of elements of order 2 in $D_8$: 9, they are $\sigma\rho^i$ and $\rho^4$, for $i=0,1,2,...,7$. I also found out that $\rho^4$ commutes with all elements of order 2, $\sigma\rho^i$ commutes with $\rho^4$ and $\sigma\rho^j$ if and only if $i-j \equiv 0 \pmod{4}$.

Here is the problem, I tried to count the subgroups in this way: choose one $\sigma\rho^i$ (8 choices) then choose one element of order two such that they commute (2 choices). So the number of subgroups is $\frac{8\times2}{3\times2}$, this does not seem correct.

Could somebody help me?

Comment: $\rho^4$ is in all of these subgroups, and each subgroup contains two of the reflections, so there are four subgroups altogether.

Comment: "this does not seem correct" I think we can confidently state that the assertion that the number of subgroups is $8/3$ is not, in fact, correct, even if we didn't know the correct answer.

Comment: @DerekHolt how did you count the subgroups? Now if  $\sigma\rho^i$  and $\sigma\rho^j$ commute then $\sigma\rho^i$$\sigma\rho^j$=$\rho^4$. Now choose an element of order 2  $\sigma\rho^i$ (8 choiches). The previous choiche determines a $\sigma\rho^j$. So you have $\frac{8}{4\times3}$ subgroups?

Comment: Why do you keep trying to divide by 3? There are eight reflections, each subgroup contains two of them, so that makes $8/2 = 4$ subgroups. You seem to be trying to make the problem more complicated than it is!

Comment: I try to explain: i divide for $3*2$ because Z2xZ2 has three elements of order 2, so I can generate it picking up an element  of order 2 (3 choiches) and another different (2 choiches).

Comment: But we do not have three choices for the first element. The first element we choose is always $\rho^4$, making one choice. Then we have eight choices for the second element, but two such choices give the same subgroup, so we have $8/2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(For convenience, let me call $r:=\rho$ and $s:=\sigma$)

We have to find the *closed* subsets $K:=\{1,a,b,c\}\subseteq D_8$ such that $a^2=b^2=c^2=1$. Order $2$ elements in $D_8$ are $r^4$ and all the reflections $r^js$; $K$ can't be made of reflections only, as the product of two distinct reflections is a rotation ($(r^is)(r^js)=r^issr^{-j}=r^{i-j}$): then, $r^4$ must be in $K$. Therefore, $K$ is of the form $K=\{1,r^4,r^is,r^js\}$, for some distinct $0\le i,j\le 7$. All the closure requirements are fulfilled if and only if $|i-j|=4$, so the sought subgroups are four, namely:

$K_1=\{1,r^4,s,r^4s\}$

$K_2=\{1,r^4,rs,r^5s\}$

$K_3=\{1,r^4,r^2s,r^6s\}$

$K_4=\{1,r^4,r^3s,r^7s\}$